# boto3 public s3 bucket: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to access my public s3 bucket in a python script.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket-nicetryfbi')
for a in bucket.objects.all():
    print(a)
```

But i recieve this exception:

```
  File "/home/philip/Devel/GetS3Contents.py", line 5, in <module>
    for a in bucket.objects.all():
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 83, in __iter__
    for page in self.pages():
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 166, in pages
    for page in pages:
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 662, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 115, in create_request
    self._event_emitter.emit(event_name, request=request,
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 162, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/home/philip/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Is it not possible to iterate trough the buckets contents while unauthorized even though the buckets access is set to public?

Comment: Do you have the AWS Cli configured on your machine ?

Comment: @luk2302 It does! Thanks!